# php - Parallel calls to query on connection object

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to implement connection to mysql via PHP and I uses this class:

```
<?php 
  class Db {
    // The database connection
    protected static $connection;

    /**
     * Connect to the database
     * 
     * @return bool false on failure / mysqli MySQLi object instance on success
     */
    public function connect() {    
        // Try and connect to the database
        if(!isset(self::$connection)) {
            // Load configuration as an array. Use the actual location of your configuration file
            $config = parse_ini_file('config.ini');
            self::$connection = new mysqli('localhost',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
        }

        // If connection was not successful, handle the error
        if(self::$connection === false) {
            // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.           
            return false;
        }

        return self::$connection;
    }

    /**
     * Query the database
     *
     * @param $query The query string
     * @return mixed The result of the mysqli::query() function
     */
    public function query($query) {
        // Connect to the database
        $connection = $this -> connect();

        // Query the database
        $result = $connection -> query($query);

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Fetch rows from the database (SELECT query)
     *
     * @param $query The query string
     * @return bool False on failure / array Database rows on success
     */
    public function select($query) {        
        $rows = array();

        $result = $this -> query($query);
        if($result === false) {         
            return false;
        }
        while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }

    /**
     * Fetch the last error from the database
     * 
     * @return string Database error message
     */
    public function error() {
        $connection = $this -> connect();
        return $connection -> error;
    }

    /**
     * Quote and escape value for use in a database query
     *
     * @param string $value The value to be quoted and escaped
     * @return string The quoted and escaped string
     */
    public function quote($value) {
        $connection = $this -> connect();
        return "'" . $connection -> real_escape_string($value) . "'";
    }

    public function setPostVarDb($postName)
    {
        $varDb = $_POST[$postName];
        $varDb = stripslashes($varDb);
        $varDb = $this -> quote($varDb);
        return $varDb;
    }

    public function setVarDb($value)
    {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
        $value = $this -> quote($value);
        return $value;
    }

} ?>
```

As you can see `$connection` configured as `static`.

When calling multiple times to `select` from homepage I get 0 results from one function (Apparently both threads reaches `query` function on the same static connection and tackles each other).

```
<?php           
       $db = new Db();                     
       $sql="SELECT Name FROM city";
       $result = $db -> select($sql);
       echo $result[0]['Name'];
?>  

  <div> And again </div>

<?php           
       $db = new Db();                     
       $sql="SELECT Name FROM city";
       $result = $db -> select($sql);
       echo $result[0]['Name'];
?>
```

If I delete `static` from `$connection` var everything works fine, but I've read that's not the best practice.
In addition, I've thought about using a lock on `$result = $connection -> query($query);` but I'm not sure that is the best practice.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Creating a connection, using it once, and throwing it in the garbage is wasteful and can be painfully slow. You really want to use a proper connection pool to do this right. You also *do not* want to be writing a wrapper around something without supporting prepared statements and placeholder values. `stripslashes` is an anachronism that has no place in your code, it destroys data when used like this.

Comment: @tadman but how does your answer relate to my question ?
maybe you right and stripslashes doesn't belong there, but still I have concurrency issue.

Comment: @tadman can you share some code ?

Comment: A db object from an include. So for that, at least the db object is not created each time.